# splitting ff_vectors in r

Tags: r, split, ff

Is there a way to perform a basic split of ff_vectors without any sums or such things? I have a ffdf called res2 consisting of 2 ff_vectors, and I want the following, from a ffdf like this:

```
A     B
a     1
a     2
b     4
b     5
```

result should be a list like with the use of split function:

```
$a 
1 2

$b
4 5
```

I want to create transactions out of these stuff and perform analysis on them, but I require to organize my data correctly first.

Comment: i have no idea what happened, but there was a suggestion to use:

    tapply(data$B, data$A, function(x) x)

which caused error:
    tapply(data$B, data$A, function(x) x)

Comment: Do you need `split(df$B, df$A)` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, but the problem is that it doesn't work with ffdf. The comment is:

    Error in as.vmode(value, vmode) : 
  argument "value" is missing, with no default

Comment: [Check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470677/using-tapply-ave-functions-for-ff-vectors-in-r).

Comment: `split(df[, 'B'], df[,'A'])`

Comment: Ronak's code worked!!! For some reason I can't transform it now the result to transcactions now, even thought the same result received through a different process worked. Error says: Error in as(i, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing “list” to “transactions”

Comment: Ronak you can add your code as an asnwer, and I will gladly accept it as an answer, if you find your ranking important :)

Comment: I posted it as an answer. As far as you getting another error is concerned, you should post a new question with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207697/parsing-as-transactions-in-r

If anyone finds the time, I'd be mostly grateful. Hopefully the apriori will work after that without any complain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try,

```
split(df[, 'B'], df[,'A'])
```

which would give

```
#$a
#[1] 1 2

#$b
#[1] 4 5
```